# Why does SFDC create a Lead via the LMA, but Checkout creates an Account when a payment is processed

Tags: isv, appexchange

I understand a Checkout transaction is "sold" - does SFDC just expect the ISV to convert the lead created via the LMA?

It would be great to hear what other ISVs are doing here.

Comment: In the case of the LMA, you get everyone that simply installs a trial of your app. It makes sense that these are leads. In the case of checkout, you have a customer actually buying your app, they are much more than just in a trial.

Comment: Are you converting the LMA Leads to Accounts by hand when sold via Checkout?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior follows the methodology design of salesforce.com. A lead is an unqualified sale opportunity, and an account is a closed sale. The idea is that sales associates would follow up on LMA-created leads to try and close the deal, while those that subscribe would be listed as accounts (so you can track the opportunities, customer portal access to cases, and so on).